# How do I create a dropdown checkbox list in Android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-menu, android-checkbox, popupmenu

I want to create a material design [exposed dropdown](https://www.material.io/components/menus#usage) menu for my Android app using Kotlin, but I want the dropdown menu to be a list of checkboxes where I can then retrieve what checkboxes the user selected programmatically.

How do I do this? Is there a library that already exists for doing this?

Comment: Use sub menu item

Comment: what do you want? dropdown is supposed to select from the list, while checkbox is select/de-select multiple items. you can try Spinner view which supposed to be the dropdown in androidl

Comment: @AIMINPAN I literally clearly stated what I wanted. Yes, the multiple items list in a dropdown is what I want.

Comment: then it is not "drop down", it is a popup dialog. you should add a button to show the pop up dialog. you need a customized layout for the dialog, a listview or recyclerview is needed.

Comment: @AIMINPAN A popup dialog is not what I want. A dropdown menu and popup dialog are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a checkable menu in `res\menu` by wrapping the items into `<group>` tag with `android:checkableBehavior="all"` attribute:

poupup_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:title="One" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:title="Two" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:title="Three" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Then inflate it programmatically, and track the checked items in an array:

```
boolean[] isChecked;
private PopupMenu mPopupMenu;


private void showPopupMenu() {

    // Button used to anchor the popup menu and to show it on its click
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    if (mPopupMenu == null) {
        //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
        mPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button);
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file
        mPopupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.poupup_menu, mPopupMenu.getMenu());
        isChecked = new boolean[mPopupMenu.getMenu().size()];
    }

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mPopupMenu.show();

            mPopupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    int position = -1;
                    
                    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.one) position = 0;
                    else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.two) position = 1;
                    else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.three) position = 2;
                    
                    if (position != -1) {
                        isChecked[position] = !isChecked[position];
                        item.setChecked(isChecked[position]);
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```